# Multiple angular form validations with an additional manual validation

Tags: angular, error-handling

I have a form with a control that has multiple validators when first set up, like this:

```
noDupesField: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]')])
```

In another section of code, I fire off an async call that checks to see if the value entered already exists in a DB of values. It then sets a NEW validator to false, but this overwrites the existing validators, effectively erasing them.

```
this.noDupesField.setErrors({ dupeDetected: true});
```

Is there a way to set validators at the start, AND to manually trigger this particular error later, while keeping those validators intact?

Comment: An async validator is not an option? What about you call get('noDupesField').errors and add or remove the key dupeDetected from the object and set it afterwards with setErrors()

Comment: This is what I had to do and seems really clunky. I had to reset all the validators that I had already set. This was manageable because I only have three fields, but having to do this on a larger form with more validators would have created a lot of maintenance code.

IMO, FormControls / FormGroup needs an "updateErrors" function, or "setErrors" should only work on existing Validators and not overwrite current ones